# SCNNode rotates inside anchor coordinate system

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit

I want to place a figure straight on the floor. I see two options where to put it:

- inside anchor's `SCNNode` with anchor's coordinates
- inside `rootNode`, in global coordinates, with `height == anchor.transform[3][1]`

I don't turn off tracking because I see that stability of tracking improves in first 10-20 second.

In the first case, my figure rotates randomly (because anchor tends to increase the extent and wants to fit extent's rectangle in the tracking area). In the second case, the figure may be upper or lower than the actual floor (I can see it by adding extra "floor" inside anchor's SCNNode).

I can use the first case and make transformations to compensate rotation but it does not look like a right solution.

What is the right way to place a figure on the floor?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have the anchor from a callback from something like `arConfiguration.planeDetection = .horizontal` where `arConfiguration` is defined as `let arConfiguration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()`.

When a callback like `func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor)` is called by ARKit you should add the node to the ARKit `scene.rootNode`. For the same plane this callback will be called: `func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didUpdate node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor)`. Then, to have the same object in the same position during the ARKit scene exploration you should act in the "add" callback.

Did i get it right?
Hope this helps

Comment: you right, I use `arConfiguration.planeDetection = .horizontal` and both `renderer` functions. I add my figure in `renderer(..., didAdd ...)` as a child of `didAdd node`, but after firing of `renderer(..., didUpdate ...)` my figure rotates. Should I add `didAdd node` to the `scene.rootNode` to fix it?

Comment: you have to do it. Adding your node to the node provided you from the `didAdd` callback constraint your node to the one that will be updated by the `didUpdate` callback. It would be the same adding your node directly in the `didUpdate`